# Ctra+enter отправка сообщений

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, подскажите в чем проблема, написал скрипт отправки сообщений, из textarea при нажатии сочетаний клавиш ctrl+enter, а он не работает. В чем моя ошибка ?

```
    <script>    
var ID = $(".reply_id").attr("id");
var reply= $("#replytext"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'reply='+ reply + '&tid=' + ID;
$(".reply"+ID).keydown(function (e) {
if ((keyCode == 10 || keyCode == 13) && event.ctrlKey) {    
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "py.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#reply_load"+ID).prepend(html);
$("#replytext"+ID).val('');    
 }
 });
}}   
</script>
```

Вот как выглядит textarea !

```
<textarea rel="12" id="replytext12" class="reply" name="reply" ></textarea>
```

Comment: keyCode точно инициализируется значением?

Comment: Вроде номера клавиш те прописаны, а нечего не происходит (

Comment: Вы откуда этот keyCode берете??? у вас на keydown повешено одно обращение e которое и описывет событие. Вас же спросили keyCode инициализирован???
вот выведите, что возваращает "e" и посотрите где коды клавиш.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И вообще у вас зоопарк (function (e) ,keyCode, event.ctrlKey... Следите за переменными все что внутри не инициализирванно
enter = 13 
А вообще у вас должно быть так

e.ctrlKey = true && e.keyCode == 13

тогда будет ctrl+enter